# Remove facebook URL parameters via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website i have facebook comment form. So, when some user answered on facebook comment, comment's author receives message with link looks like `http://somesite/?p=650336994452395724_787132&fb_comment_id=fbc_206901222839669_334304_206901256172999#f2c762c5d4` but comments avaiable only by `http://somesite/?p=650336994452395724_787132` url.

So, i need to remove all parameters after `http://somesite/?p=650336994452395724_787132` by .htaccess. I've tried to do that with next code 
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fb_comment_id=.*$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]` 
but it gives me wrong url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=[^&]+)& [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1# [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: It gives url like http://website/?p=65033#f2c762c5d4 and chrome error "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: Is it different from your expected URL? What was original URL?

Comment: http://somesite/?p=650336994452395724_787132 - that what i need to get from http://somesite/?p=650336994452395724_787132&fb_comment_id=fbc_206901222839669_334304_206901256172999#f2c762c5d4

Comment: Your code removes all between http://website/?p=65033 and #f2c762c5d4. And it still gives urls like website/?p=65033#f2c762c5d4

Comment: For you given link it redirects to `/?p=650336994452395724_787132#f2c762c5d4` (text after `#` can also be truncated if you like)

Comment: See updated code, this will redirect to: `/?p=650336994452395724_787132#`

Comment: Oh no worries, I know 301 does cause this while testing. Glad it worked out.